# Adding rows in data table in c#

Tags: c#

I have created a data table in my Application start method and I am trying to add rows to this data table from my session start method. When I try to add rows, it gives an error on the data table that

> the name does not exists in the current context.

I am a beginner to programming. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
// application begins
void Application_Start(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("session_id", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("username",   System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("login_time", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ip_address", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));

    Application["visitorTable"] = dt;
}

// browser's first visit to the page, (session starts)
void Session_Start(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        Application.Lock();

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["session_id"] = (System.String)HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID; // session id
        dr["ip_address"] = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]; //ip-address

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dt = (Database)Application["visitorTable"];

        Application["visitorTable"] = dt;

        Application.UnLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried loading `dt` from `Application["visitorTable"]`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. @Grant Winney: I tried moving        DataRow dr= (DataTable)Application["visitorTable"]; and I am still seeing the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

[Dynamically create DataTable and bind to GridView in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-create-DataTable-and-bind-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)

it might be help you

```html
DataTable dt;
void Application_Start(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
    dt= new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("session_id", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("username",   System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("login_time", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ip_address", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));

    Application["visitorTable"] = dt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Umar. I checked this link. In my code i want to save the session data and the ip address of the user session. So I was trying to capture this data in the session start method and I am getting error when I try to add rows. In the link, table creation, adding columns and rows are done in one method. I want to see if I can create the table in a different method and add rows to the table in a different method.

Comment: DataTable dt;
void Application_Start(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
    dt= new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("session_id", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("username",   System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("login_time", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ip_address", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));

    Application["visitorTable"] = dt;
}
you try this

Comment: Thanks Umar. This fixed the issue.

Comment: Mark this answer if it fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the table name when creating a new DataTabe...

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("VisitorTable");
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("session_id", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("username",   System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("login_time", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ip_address", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));

    Application["visitorTable"] = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // you create it like this 
    Application["visitorTable"] = dt;

    // and you read it like this
    dt = (Database)Application["VisitorTable"];
```

Notice the issue?

Also you don't need to rely on reflection to get a type's description, a simple compile time `typeof(string)` and `typeof(DateTime)` will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Blindy. Can you tell me exactly what changes to make.

Comment: he means you are case-insensitive. *pun intended*

Answer (score 0):

when your are executing following code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("session_id", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("username",   System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("login_time", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ip_address", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
```

have you checked whether your dt added with column name specified ? 
or dt is generated with columns Column1,colum2,column3 
if those are generated with Column1,colum2,column3 ths why you ll be facing above error  , 
rename column with your name of dt

Comment: Can you tell me how can I check this?